# Unable to convert a .h5 fileto a tflite model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I've trained a model and saved it as a h5 file. Since I want to use this in my android application, I'm looking to convert it to tflite on Colab. This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('Final_model.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: type object 'TFLiteConverter' has no attribute 'from_keras_model'
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to `StackOverflow`! What's your `tensorflow` version? You can just `print(tf.__version__)` to check it easily.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke thanks! My version is 1.15.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `colab's` default `tensorflow`, which is `1.15.0`.

You can download newest version by issuing from colab's cell:

`!pip install --upgrade pip && pip install tensorflow`.

You may have to uninstall `tensorflow` version 1.15.0 beforehand via this command:

`!pip uninstall tensorflow (or tensorflow-gpu)`.

You should be able to run `tf2.x` code just fine after that.

**Note:** Soon TF2.0 will be the default version and this workaround is temporary.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Tensorflow 1.x which in this context has a slightly [different API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#from_keras_model_file). What you should use is `from_keras_model_file`, i.e.:

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('Final_model.h5')
```

Comment: This is the error I get: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Sequential

Comment: @ShlokKhemani That's because you are supposed to provide path to the model rather than the model itself. I edited the answer to make sure it's clear.